# Find value between array values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, lookup

I have a large array and would like to find between which array values the search value would appear.

A simplified version of this array is as follows:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [min] => 0
        [max] => 4.999
        [val] => low
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [min] => 5
        [max] => 9.999
        [val] => med
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [min] => 10
        [max] => 14.999
        [val] => high
    )
```

So if I was to search for 6.2 the returned result would be the array value 'med'

Is there a built in function that can easily walk over the array to make this calculation or would I need to set up a foreach loop

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a simple  foreach would be fast enough, with some precaution in
floating point comparisons : see it here : http://codepad.org/sZkDJJQb

```
   <?php

$rangeArray = array(
    array( 'min' => 0, 'max' => 4.999,  'val' => 'low'),
    array( 'min' => 5, 'max' => 9.999,  'val' => 'med'),
    array( 'min' => 10, 'max' => 14.999,  'val' => 'high'),
    );

$input = 6.2;
$precision = 0.00001 ;

foreach($rangeArray as $current)
{
  if( ($input - $current['min']) > $precision and ($input - $current['max']) <= $precision )
    {
      echo $current['val'];
      break;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: It certainly did the trick, it was the break; that I'd forgotten to use and it's a very large array! Thank you!